# Is it possible to output video of my iPhone application running on a device?

Tags: iphone

I am working on an app for a client where he will be showing it in a board from to a group of directors for a serious presentation. Because the iPhone is so small, it wouldn't make sense to have him demo the app on the actual device because no one would see anything.

Is it possible to have the screen output on a computer or tv so that everyone in the room can see what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dragonforged.com/DFVideoOut.shtml

For outputting video off an App from the iPhone/iPod.

Demo of the software http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upfTZRlszJo

Comment: Note this might not be usable for something you would send to the app store, but is definitely something you could embed in an AdHoc build for a demo.

Comment: I tried this option, as well as some others out there, notably http://austinfrance.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/iphone-tv-out-tutorial/ and http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/3 - but get the same issue with all of them, which is basically that the `MPTVOutWindow` object does not recognize the selector `initWithVideoView`. What am I missing here? I did include the MediaPlayer.framework in my project.

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE:*** The AV cables described below **will not** work. Apple only enables TV output for [YouTube, iPod Video and iPod Photos](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=597640).

---

From [Apple's support site](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1454):

> All you need to get TV out is a compatible iPod or iPhone and the correct cable. If your device works with the component and composite cables, then the choice depends on the TV(s) you will be connecting to.

You need either the [Composite AV Cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB129LL/B?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY) or the [Component AV Cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB128LL/B?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY). Both cables connect to the iPhone's dock connector.

Comment: That just allows you to play videos from your iPhone, it doesn't actually show your screen does it??

Comment: I think you may be right. I just came back here to post that.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you're Steve Jobs.

Use the emulator to demo the app via a laptop.

Then pass around an iPhone for the 'hands on' time.

If it's not a phone app, but suitable for the iPod touch, then buy a dozen of them to pass around as demos.

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly what you want but:

[www.projectaphone.com](http://www.projectaphone.com/)

You cant pass the phone around, but in reality - you need to see the finger interaction anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if an overhead projector would work - with the projector light turned off of course. Maybe the light emitted from the iPhone would be sufficient in a dark room?

Answer (score 0):

You could demo it on the simulator.

Some applications for jailbroken iPhones exist to let an AV cable work in any application. The ones that come to mind are iPhone-TVOut (http://code.google.com/p/iphone-tvout/) and ScreenSplitr.